# Comments and post dates not showing up correctly on "posts page"

Tags: comments

I have customized the Twenty Fourteen theme to use the page "news" for my posts page because I have static frontpage.

When you view my [news page](http://50.87.248.141/~johnseab/news), comments don't show up, even though they are enabled, and when you go to the specific post, they are. Is there any way to add the comments to the news page, where the posts are supposed to show up in full form?

I also can't get the date of the [post](http://50.87.248.141/~johnseab/thoughts-on-brett-morgans-documentary-kurt-cobain-montage-of-heck/news/thoughts-on-brett-morgans-documentary-kurt-cobain-montage-of-heck/) to show up in either place and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing `category.php` – or `category-news.php` if you have it – your CSS seems to indicate you've created a "news" category, but you'll hopefully know which files you've edited - and adding:

```
$withcomments = 1;

// If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
    comments_template();
}
```

between `get_template_part('content', get_post_format() );` and the `endwhile` (in the bit where WordPress loops through each post.)

This will add a comments form after every post on a category page (if you have loads of posts, especially short ones, you may find it much too cluttered, though.)

As for the **date**, the Twenty Fourteen theme has a function called `twentyfourteen_posted_on()` (it's in the `template-tags.php` file) - it prints the date and the author.

As you'll see if you inspect how it works, you can add:

`echo esc_html( get_the_date() );`

to print the date by itself, and [get_the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) takes a parameter that lets you customise how the date (and/or time) is displayed using the standard [PHP date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

You may also find the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) useful - it explains which template files WordPress loads to display different pages.

Comment: Thanks William, I read a few threads about get the date, which is in my template-tags folder already. I guess that's why I am confused. If you view source you can even see that it's in the source code (date of post) but isn't showing up. I basically made the news category so that it would show the posts, otherwise uncategorized they were displaying error pages when I tried to view them. I added the comment code you gave me to category.php but it's still not working. Thank you for taking the time to answer though!

Comment: Looks like the date is missing because you have `.entry-header { display: none; }` in your CSS - so you would need to get rid of that, restyle the header to fit your design and also remove the duplicate post title.

Comment: Ok, I am really embarrassed now because I actually know css and was looking for entry-date! I am SO relieved and grateful to you William! It's working beautifully. Thank you again so much for your great advice!

Comment: No problem don't worry about it Leah (I didn't think to look at the HTML source either…) W.